# Safely strip metadata from images in a folder, add a value to some tags

Tags: images, metadata, exif, exiftool

I have a directory structure that contains a lot of JPEG/JPG, PNG, SVG, and WEBP images in several subdirectories. I want to strip all metadata from these images except anything that would be necessary for the images to function (colour profiles, orientation, etc.) as well as the date. I then want to modify each one's OwnerName and Artist fields to a given string.

Piecing together info from the docs I've come up with the following command:

```
exiftool -a -r -overwrite_original -ext JPG -ext JPEG -ext PNG -ext SVG -ext WEBP -all= \ 
--icc_profile:all -OwnerName="Hashim" -Artist="Hashim" -tagsfromfile @ -ColorSpaceTags myfolder
```

This contains everything I want to do except leave the dates intact, as I'm unsure which date tags I should be using.

Is this command suitable for what I'm trying to do here? Do the other file types maybe require more delicate handling that it would be safer to process them separately from the JPGs?

If this command is good enough, which of the [EXIF](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/EXIF.html), [XMP](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/XMP.html) or [IPTC](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/IPTC.html) date tags should I be leaving in?

Comment: The question needs to be less opinion-based IMO. WHat does "best" date exactly mean?  Please describe what you want to use it for exactly and also where.

Comment: [Related exiftool forum post](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=15261.0)  Answer from there needs to be added here.

Comment: I would guess that the way to tell if the command is suitable would be to run it, correct? Have you done that yet? Is there something that indicates it may NOT be suitable?

Comment: @music2myear Incorrect. I'm not sure which enterprise environments you've worked in but the ones I work for you don't run a potentially destructive command on thousands of files blindly without lots of double-checking and confirmation, it's much less time-consuming than restoring everything from backups. Not to mention that, as mentioned in the question, the command was incomplete.

Comment: You can easily copy some data to other folders to perform tests on. The enterprise environments I've worked in require testing, preferably with live data, not taking the word of randoms online. You haven't defined what sort of date format is needed, AND, it literally says "Is this command suitable for my needs...". Editing your question to focus on the single specific issue, and telling us what you have tried so far, would improve this question a lot.

Comment: @music2myear Why would I need to include what I've tried when I've included most of the command needed for the purpose? Do you not think that shows sufficient enough research? A date format is not needed because no new date is being written. Anyone actually familiar with the tools in question will know this, as opposed to dabblers picking at the question in the hopes of finding reasons to close it.

Answer (score 1):

Many thanks to [StarGeek](https://superuser.com/users/314998/stargeek) for his invaluable [help in the ExifTool forum](https://exiftool.org/forum/index.php?topic=15261.0), including confirming that:

- PNG and WEBP files do not need any special handling to safely remove metadata, similar to how TIFF files do
- SVG files do not have file-level metadata at all and therefore ExifTool cannot be used to write metadata for them

Thanks to his recommendations I've managed to get the command down to the bare minimum needed:

```
exiftool -P -a -r -ext JPG -ext JPEG -ext PNG -ext WEBP -all= -OwnerName="Hashim" \ 
-Artist="Hashim" -tagsfromfile @ -ColorSpaceTags -Orientation -AllDates path/to/images/
```

This included adding the `-P` tag to force ExifTool to preserve filesystem dates instead of clearing them by default, and adding the `-Orientation` and `-AllDates` tags to prevent deletion of the orientation and date metadata.

I also removed the redundant `--icc_profile:all` because `-ColorSpaceTags` is a [shortcut](https://exiftool.org/TagNames/Shortcuts.html) that includes the ICC profile in addition to other colour-related tags.

Lastly I removed `-overwrite_original` because I prefer ExifTool's default behavior here: it backs up the original file by renaming it (appending `_original` to the end of the filename).

Adding `-overwrite_original` will cause these backups to be automatically deleted. Not only does this remove the ability to quickly restore your images if something goes wrong, but if you're stripping metadata to optimise bandwidth and/or storage space you'll no longer be able to compare the original image with the stripped image to confirm your optimisation gains.

Instead of using `-overwrite-original`, you can just wait however long it takes to confirm that all your images look the same as they did before, and then run the following command to delete the unneeded backup files:

```
find /path/to/images -type f -name "*_original" -delete
```